# How to create a symmetrical data frame in R based on another symmetrical dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, lookup

I have this data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(product=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), ID=c(1,1,2,2,1))
```

[image]

and another (symmetrical) data frame.

```
ID_table <- data.frame("ID 1" = c(10, 50), "ID 2" = c(50, 10))
```

[image]

How can I create a 5 by 5 product-level data frame based on the value of ID?

Here is the desired output:

[image]

The number from A to B is 10 because A and B have the same ID=1.
The number from A to C is 50 because A has ID 1 but C has ID 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt using `outer` to generate the combinations of each `df$ID` and use them to subset your `ID_table`:

```
idnm <- setNames(df$ID,df$product)
o <- outer(idnm, idnm, FUN=function(x,y) ID_table[cbind(x,y)] )
o
#   A  B  C  D  E
#A 10 10 50 50 10
#B 10 10 50 50 10
#C 50 50 10 10 50
#D 50 50 10 10 50
#E 10 10 50 50 10
```

Comment: This works. Can you explain why we need cbind? Why not just ID_table[x,y]?  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Ketty - you have to use `cbind` because `outer` tries to use the specified `FUN=` taking the whole of `x` and `y` at once and then inserting the result into a matrix. So `outer(1:3, 2:4, FUN=\`+\`)` does `1:3 + rep(2:4,each=3)` not separate `1+2` then `2+2` then `3+2` then `1+3` ... etc calculations. And if you look at the results of `ID_table[idnm, rep(idnm,each=5)]` and `ID_table[cbind(idnm, rep(idnm,each=5))]` , you'll see the second example actually selects the proper row+col calculations while the first gives far too many values.

Comment: Thanks so much, thelatemail.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `table` and `tcrossprod` to get the following

```
out <- tcrossprod(table(df))
out
#       product
#product A B C D E
#      A 1 1 0 0 1
#      B 1 1 0 0 1
#      C 0 0 1 1 0
#      D 0 0 1 1 0
#      E 1 1 0 0 1
```

Now you would only need to replace the values by `10` and `50`

```
as.data.frame(ifelse(out == 1, 10, 50))
#   A  B  C  D  E
#A 10 10 50 50 10
#B 10 10 50 50 10
#C 50 50 10 10 50
#D 50 50 10 10 50
#E 10 10 50 50 10
```

---

The result of `table(df)` is

```
table(df)
#       ID
#product 1 2
#      A 1 0
#      B 1 0
#      C 0 1
#      D 0 1
#      E 1 0
```

While the result of `tcrossprod(table(df))` is the same as doing

```
table(df) %*% t(table(df))
```

Comment: I don't think this would work since ID_table might be any n by n matrix (n > 2). Thus, as.data.frame(ifelse(out == 1, 10, 50)) won't work. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It works for the data you provided. You might update your post with a better example.

Comment: I tried to make the example as simple as possible. Will create a better example next time. Thanks.